# What controls whether the main layout file is "main.xml" or something else?

Tags: android

I was going through the tutorial in "Learning Android" where it suggested to rename the main layout file from "main.xml" to "status.xml".  I only know I haven't seen this suggestion before (making the main layout file name more application-specific), but I don't know that there's anything particularly wrong with it.

However, I'm wondering, how does the build know to look for "main.xml", or "status.xml", for that matter.  Does it just look for any layout file in the res/layout directory?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Look at your Activity and you will see a line like this:

```
setContentView(R.layout.main);
```

There is an auto-generated class called R.java in the gen directory which identifies all the resources in your application. So all the layout xml files in res/layout directory will be defined in R.java. setContentView associates the layout file with that particular Activity.

Comment: Yeah, most of that didn't tell me anything new.  You did implicitly answer my actual question, which is "does it look for any layout file in the res/layout directory?".  The answer appears to be "yes".

Answer (score 0):

You select the XML to use by calling [setContentView](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html#setContentView%28android.view.View%29).